# When using turbulance to create a grass animation, the effect of the turbulance eventually fades out

Tags: particles, force-fields

I used a turbulence force field to create a grass animation for 300 frames. At the start the turbulence is affecting the grass very much but about at 100 frames it starts to slow down and eventually nearly stops at around 200 frames. What to do to keep the effect going?
(Using Blender 2.90.1)

[Here's a video of the issue I am facing.](https://www.mediafire.com/file/52e1hm3ix0vlqbx/20210105_214516.mp4/file)

These are the particle setting for the Grass:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here are the physics propeties for the turbulance:

[image]

Comment: could you share your file please?  I think I have an idea of why this might be happening, but I'll need to take a closer look first.  You can use this link to share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @ETHANDAY It is taking forver to upload though I have a good interenet connection. Is there any other way to share the file?

Comment: hm, its probably because your file size is too big.  Is there anything else in your scene besides the grass?  If there is, try making a separate file and import it without anything except for the grass and anything else that effects it.  If it is just the grass in your scene, maybe make another file and import just a small section of your grass.  and if that doesn't work, you could also try uploading it to google drive and get a shareable link.

Comment: let me know what you find out

Comment: @ETHANDAY https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R_0tczIzKHpOogmmrFb6bbLdhuHMUIFD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ETHANDAY Here's the google drive link to the blend file with just the grass, the plane, and the force field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118076/discussion-between-abhishek-dey-and-ethan-day).

Comment: iirc fields are dependent on the physics cache start and end frame, which may end at 100 by default

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get this process to work, still don't know why. But then I simply animated my force field to go from one position to another and that seems to do the job.